# Container App fails with error "Error provisioning the container app. Container failed to start-up"

Tags: azure-container-apps

Was creating an Azure Container App, I got an error when creating of "Error provisioning the container app. Container '' failed to start-up. Please check Log Analytics workspace for container logs."  When I went to Log Analytics and Logs I didn't see any tables. Why did the container fail?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes Log Analytics has a few minutes delay to ingest the logs. In my case after I waited for 3 or so minutes and went back to the logs screen, I had tables populated and could see the console logs that emitted from my container that helped me understand why it failed to startup.

Comment: same observation here